# How to Handle Concurrency control in PHP & MySql

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, multiple-forms

I am using the core PHP & Mysql to building a project and I have a registration form that is divided into multiforms (say 4 to 5 forms) and each form is getting user details from new users, and i want to save the users data to database tables at the final submission of form, so my question is where to save the data got from mutiforms?

situation: 1. if i use the session variable to store the forms data, then it will take too much server resources to store data to session or worse if i got many users at the same time of registration. so sessions can slow down the server.

Please suggest a solution for that.

Comment: Where did you get that 100 concurrent users having data in sessions would slow down the server? How massive are you forms? Maybe if tthe server an old Texas Instruments calculator. :-) Either way, I would store the information using Local Storage (storing the form data in the users browser) until the last submission.

Comment: u mean we can use the cookie?

Comment: what if the cookie can hack?

Comment: cookies != sessions ...

Comment: No, I mean  [local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). Why would someone hack their own information they just supplied to your form?

Comment: and yes i edited the question, for 100 users line

Comment: but still sessions would be a fine idea used by most.'local storage' a new option

Comment: @rtfm where does session exists on server in RAM or what?

Comment: sessions by default are files on the server. they can also be stored in a db.

Comment: ok sessions would be fine?

Comment: yes. one random work server - current open sessions 5300, no problems there

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson thank you guys for making me clear for this question i would probably go with session..

Answer (score 0):

Store all data in a database and just match data with user's session id.

Comment: u mean i have to make multiple data queries at the submission of mini forms.

Comment: What's are "multiple data queries"?

Comment: i mean multiple insert queries at the forms steps

Comment: Each form, one query sto insert data.

Comment: Or, like suggested by O.Palm, ... just keep data in a javascript variable.

Comment: i used the session thing..:)

Answer (score 0):

you can get all fields in javascript and send to server with ajax. Other solution is request individual form and use SQL transactions.